# Objective C - Setting UIPickerView Delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, datasource, uipickerview

I have one mainViewController and I have a UIPickerView. Now all is set up well, but when I run the app and select the textField I get Question Marks in my UIPickerView list.

Now I have just learned that, that is because I have not connected the delegate for it.
However if I connect the delegate for it, then the textField does not get populated.

The TextField is in mainViewController.

So in my MainViewController.h I have imported the UIPickerView and have this code - which is all without errors. _pv is the UIPickerView.

```
 _pv = [[CategoryPicker alloc] init];

[_pv.categoryPicker setDelegate:self];
[_pv.categoryPicker setDataSource:_pv];

[_appPriorityTxtFld setInputView:_pv];
[_appPriorityTxtFld setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
```

Now as you can see the Delegate is set to self, this will allow for the textField to be populated.

If I set that to _pv the then I get the list displayed properly, but the textField is not populated.

What am I missing??

Cheers

Comment: Did you implement `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`? You should update the text field's text in that method.

Comment: In the UIPickerView? so I need to import it the other way around?

Comment: But yeah I have implemented that - that is why I am getting the result in the textField.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement the picker delegate method "pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:" and you need to set the selected text as textfild text. see the following code for reference,

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

I think this may useful.

Comment: Yeah that more or less did the trick. It got the picker functioning properly, but I was more hoping to subclass it I think.

Comment: you can do one thing for subclass it. That is, implement all the delegate and data source methods for picker in custom class and pass the selected string to textfield's text. So that, you need not to set the different delegate and datasource, every thing will be in custom class itself. The only thing is, you need to access the text field object while selecting the row in picker.